# Efficietly repeat data.table in a list, sequentially replacing columns with the same names from another data.table in a loop

Tags: r, loops, replace, data.table, updates

I have two `data.table`s:

```
x <- data.table(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1), b = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 2), c = c(3, 4, 1, 2, 3))
y <- data.table(a = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1), b = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), c = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create a list of `y` with length of the number of its columns where every next column is replaced by the values of the same column in `x`. The desired result shall look like this:

```
[[1]]
   a b c
1: 1 0 0
2: 2 1 0
3: 3 0 0
4: 4 0 0
5: 1 0 1

[[2]]
   a b c
1: 1 2 0
2: 0 3 0
3: 0 4 0
4: 0 1 0
5: 1 2 1

[[3]]
   a b c
1: 1 0 3
2: 0 1 4
3: 0 0 1
4: 0 0 2
5: 1 0 3
```

What I tried:

```
z <- lapply(names(x), function(i) {
  x[ , i, with = FALSE]
})

w <- rep(list(y), ncol(y))

myfun <- function(obj1, obj2) {
  cbind(obj1, obj2)
}

u <- Map(myfun, obj1 = z, obj2 = w)

u <- lapply(u, function(i) {
  setcolorder(i[ , unique(names(i)), with = FALSE], names(x))
})
```

It gives me the desired result, but is very clumsy and requires too many step, hence, it is probably inefficient with larger `data.table`s. I would like to have it more in the `data.table` way. I tried something which I assumed would work:

```
lapply(names(x), function(i) {
  y[ , (i) := x[ , i, with = FALSE]]
})
```

However, it returns the first list component empty and copies all the values of `x` into the next list components.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we may need a `copy` of the 'y' while creating the `list` 'w' instead of

```
w <- rep(list(y), ncol(y))
```

It is tempting to go for the below expression of `rep`.  However, that have an issue in the `w` elements as these are pointing to the same location in memory

```
w <- rep(list(copy(x)), ncol(y))
```

The assignment (`:=`) by reference changes the column values in each loop because they reference to the same object in memory.  In the first case, after the assignment, it changes 'y' too along with 'w' `list` elements.  Second case, it can change only 'w' and leave 'y' because we `copy`ied.  To understand the behavior, do a `set` assignment in a `for` loop

```
for(j in seq_along(x)) {print(w[[j]][[j]])
        set(w[[j]], i = NULL, j =j, x[[j]])
        print("----")
        print(w[[j]])
   }
```

Inorder to avoid that, use `replicate`

```
w <- replicate(ncol(y), copy(y), simplify = FALSE)
```

and then do the `for` loop (after recreating the objects again as the values were replaced from the previous run)

```
for(j in seq_along(x)) {print(w[[j]][[j]])
        set(w[[j]], i = NULL, j =j, x[[j]])
        print("----")
        print(w[[j]])
   }
```

Or a `Map` based assignment

```
Map(function(u, v) u[, (v) := x[[v]]][],  w, names(x))
#[[1]]
#   a b c
#1: 1 0 0
#2: 2 1 0
#3: 3 0 0
#4: 4 0 0
#5: 1 0 1

#[[2]]
#   a b c
#1: 1 2 0
#2: 0 3 0
#3: 0 4 0
#4: 0 1 0
#5: 1 2 1

#[[3]]
#   a b c
#1: 1 0 3
#2: 0 1 4
#3: 0 0 1
#4: 0 0 2
#5: 1 0 3
```

---

Instead of assignment by reference, it can be done with a simple `Map` from `base R` if we have not `copy`ied the 'y' object while creating 'w'

```
Map(function(u, v) {u[[v]] <- x[[v]]
                    u}, w, names(x))
```

---

Comment: As usual, quick response with a thorough explanation. Thank you very much!